# UITableView with SearchBar does not display ScopeBar correctly in XCode 6

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, xcode6

So I have the following problem with XCode 6.

Without typing any code, in Xcode 6, I create a simple view application containing a `NavigationController` and a `TableViewController`. In the `TableView` I add a `SearchBar` at the top. I then enable `Shows Cancel Button` and `Shows Scope Bar`.

This results in the following picture in which you can see that the `searchBar` is some kind of stretched. This appears when I click on the `Shows Scope Bar`, as if it wanted to show the room used by the `searchbar` plus the `scope bar`. However the scope bar is not seen. And when you look closely you can see a light blue line, actually the scopebar is behind the searchbar.

As can be seen this is confirmed in the second picutre, in the simulator the scope bar is 'behind' the search bar.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

**Note that the bug is also present in a iOS7 project build with Xcode 6 and run a on real device with iOS7**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same issue on Xcode 6.3.1, iOS 8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This issue has been corrected in Xcode 6.1

---

I found an answer to my own question. As this can be useful to others I let my question and my answer on  SO open.

The problem I describe seems to be a bug in XCode 6. At least many people reported the bug on radar.

The thing is to force the `SearchBar` to size itself. This can be done in `viewDidLoad`.

```
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

and the result is given in the following picture

[image]

Comment: But how does this solve the problem in the storyboard?

Comment: @BenjaminStark I am not sure I understand your question. Everything is set in the storyboard witout any line of code except the self.searchBar.sizeToFit(). Of course the visual appearance in the storyboard is still wrong, but when run it layout out properly. Note that I didn't test this on recent Xcode versions. If the problem is solved in recent version I should perhaps remove this question and the related answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I am running the current version of Xcode (7.1) and the weird stretched look of the searchBar object is still happening in the storyboard when the segmented control is turned on.  The output in the simulator is not stretched, but the stretched object in the storyboard interferes with the ability to arrange objects properly in the attached tableView.  Point being, your code is no longer necessary, but the issue as a whole is still not corrected.